# IE8 freeze with responsive.css active // some classes don't work anymore in FF chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Since this morning i've a strange problem:

IE8 freeze completly with a certain css file active; if i comment out the file, the site is loading fine, so it's definitly this file.
Also, Chrome and firefox won't accept only some classes in the same css file (??).
The classes simply won't appear in the chrome inspector.
I've read again and again the file, but i can't find any errors.
The website is still hosted on localhost.

[HERE](http://zengrafic.com/zentest/responsive.css) is the link to the css file.

In any case it's a weird problem.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Any chance you're using respond.js?

Comment: you can probably do a better job about .dx > * > * > .td {...}, also media queries don't work in IE8 unless you got some js file to go with it. Also is your IE8 going into compatibility mode by itself? I have had that happen when I was doing responsive coding. Eventually I had to switch to a lighter js lib for IE8 which only detected max/min width instead of everything

Comment: But the weird thing is that the whole code was working perfectly until last night. I know that the css3 media queries aren't working in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing looks abnormal.
So the best method might be to test blocks of code from that file to find the root of your problem.

I would first test on another computer's IE8 to see if the problem exists or is an isolated incidence.

Then, I'd test by removing half of the CSS code and find out if the other half still works and then vice versa. Instead of looking through your entire CSS line-by-line, formulate an easier, testable solution.

Answer (score 0):

After another look on the file i've found the problem: there was missing a media query bracket before

```
@media (max-width: 360px)
```

But still cannot understand why IE8 is freezing without an { (??)